# How can i play an intro on android app

Tags: android

Just a little video, like an animation, as a logo, just 5-7 seconds and than the app should appear, just an easy i think video player no buttons no clicks.

Can you tell me what should i do ?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=xzm2VIn0NND9ugSum4C4Ag&ved=0CAMQ1S4#q=android+splash+screen

Comment: When did you want to show video ? At the first time only or every time app opens up ?

Comment: It will be possible fro videos too ?

Comment: When I open the app, like logo on a game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your intro video file in res/raw folder and Set splash Layout as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
</VideoView>
```

and in source code write :

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro_splash));
    videoview.setMediaController(null);
    videoview.start();
    videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,AbcActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
```